# Mysql Table Update operation failing for no apparent reason

Tags: php, mysql, decimal

I have written some PHP/mysql code for a form-based subtitling program -- but there is one field in particular that I cannot get MYSQL to UPDATE for me.  I have been looking for the problem for hours and I just can't find it.  Below is, I think, the most relevant piece of code for resolving the problem.  The field in question (TotalSeconds) definitely exists on the 'captions' table and, as the comments show below, the `$TotalSeconds` string also exists (at least prior to the update attempt)  -- and yet all attempts to update the TotalSeconds field with the `$TotalSeconds` string value are failing.  The TotalSeconds field, by the way, is of the type `DECIMAL(11,3)` (which must be related to my problem, since I'm new to using that field type).

```
$TotalSeconds=$_REQUEST['TotalSeconds'];

/* NOTE: I can get the TotalSeconds string variable to echo successfully before the update attempt below */

$result=mysql_query("UPDATE captions SET TotalSeconds='$TotalSeconds' WHERE ID='ThisID'") or die(mysql_error());
$k=mysql_affected_rows();
```

And yet the UPDATE operation above never works.  The affected rows value always = 0.  And yet I have nine other fields which are set to update the same way, and none of the others give me any trouble at all.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: What is ThisID.Is it a variable or string? This cause only the problem?

Comment: how did you get this 'thisid'

Comment: did you try removing quotes ( ' ' ) from $TotalSeconds in your query? If the field is decimal and not string you should not use quotes (same for ID as well)

Comment: the $TotalSeconds should not be in quotes as it is a variable

Comment: I've removed the quotes -- still no luck.  The ThisID is from a hidden field in the form -- and it identifies the record that is being updated.  The ThisID field is working in nine other UPDATE statements that are identical except for the field name being updated.

Comment: Question solved, thanks. I could never locate a typo -- but I retyped the UPDATE line and it now works. Should have tried that long ago.

Answer (score 0):

OP says there was a typo.

(Now, not 'Unanswered'.)